# Sharepoint 2013: changing column order is not refleted in the list

Tags: list, column

I changed the column order on a list item. These changes are reflected in the "column ordering" view. However, the changes are NOT reflected in the actual list layout.
I tried emptying the browser cache, tried IE and FF, no results...

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/ibarfckod/desired_column_order.jpg]

[image]

Comment: That is because this view is different and the list default view is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you change the order of the default view (or any other view that you are using).
The second image is of a list view where the ordering needs to be changed & not the actual order in the list settings.

Go to list -> Ribbon -> List -> Modify VIEW, then give required ordering & say OK. (here ensure that default view is selected)

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same issue! That helped!